# Powershell copy from linux samba to local windows server folder

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, samba

I need to copy a file from a Linux samba server to various Windows Server 2008.
The shared folder has a specific login and is read-only.
I can access and copy the shared file using Windows Explorer without a problem.

But, when using PowerShell to copy the file, it always give an error as shown below.
I have tried using Copy-item, robocopy and bitstransfer but they all give an error.

```
    $arq = "file.zip"
    $downloadSource = "\\domain.or.ip\sharedfolder\$arq"
    echo $downloadSource

    Copy-Item -Path "$downloadSource" -Destination ".\$arqAgenteZabbix"
```

this method gives me the following error

> Copy-Item : Access denied
>
> - CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (\domain.or.ip\sharedfolder\file.zip:String) [Copy-Item], UnauthorizedAc
>   cessException
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId : ItemExistsUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
>   ...
>   Copy-Item: path not found...

So, I tried adding a credential parameter

```
    $credencial = New-PSSession -ComputerName "serverhostname" -Credential "serverhostname\sharedfolder"
    Copy-Item -Path "$downloadSource" -Destination ".\$arqAgenteZabbix" -ToSession $credencial
```

But received this error after typing my password:

> "New-PSSession : [pxl0mon00013] Fail to connect to remote server >serverhostname ...
> WinRM cannot process the request... error 0x80090311 ...
>
> - CategoryInfo          : OpenError (System.Manageme....RemoteRunspace:RemoteRunspace) [New-PSSession], PSRemotin
>   gTransportException
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId : AuthenticationFailed,PSSessionOpenFailed

Then, I decided to give BitsTransfer a shot.

```
Import-Module bitstransfer
    $arq = "file.zip"
    $downloadSource = "\\domain.or.ip\sharedfolder\$arq"

    Start-BitsTransfer -DisplayName DownloadName `
        -TransferType Download `
        -Source $downloadSource `
        -Destination .\$arq
```

And it also gave me an error:

> Start-BitsTransfer : path not found
> '\domain.or.ip\sharedfolder\file.zip' does not exist.
>
> - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (\domain.or.ip\sharedfolder\file.zip:String) [Start-BitsTransfer], ParentC
>   ontainsErrorRecordException
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.BackgroundIntelligentTransfer.Management.NewBitsTransferCommand

How can I make this file copy, please?

EDIT - 20190403

I tried the following:

```
get-childitem \\domain.or.ip\sharedfolder\
```

which resulted in:

```
Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path '\\domain.or.ip\sharedfolder\' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:3
+ ls <<<<  \\domain.or.ip\sharedfolder\
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (\domain.or.ip\sharedfolder\:String) [Get-ChildItem], ItemNotFo
   undException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

So, I opened Explorer and pasted \domain.or.ip\sharedfolder\ at the address bar. It asked me for username and password, then, the file was available.
After that, I returned to PowerShell and tried once again the same Get-ChildItem cmdlet. Then, I was able to list the shared folder contents as expected.

```
    Directory: \\domain.or.ip\sharedfolder
Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---        01/04/2019     10:06    3896455 file.zip
```

Finally, I tried:

```
Copy-Item -Path \\domain.or.ip\sharedfolder\file.zip -Destination ".\file.zip"
```

And it was copied successfully.

Well, only after I entered my login information in Explorer that PowerShell was able to find the shared folder.
But I need it to copy without having to open explorer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to successfully copy the shared file in a relative simple way. I used "NET USE" command to open a session and copy the file, like shown below.

```
$arq = "file.zip"
$downloadSource = "\\domain.or.ip\sharedfolder"

    net use $downloadSource /persistent:no /user:[user] [pass]
    Copy-Item -Path "$downloadSource\$arq" -Destination ".\$arq"
    net use $downloadSource /delete
```

Now, a new challenge... encrypt the clear-text password.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide alternate credentials with `Invoke-Command`:

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {
$arq = "file.zip"
$downloadSource = "\\domain.or.ip\sharedfolder\$arq"
echo $downloadSource
Copy-Item -Path "$downloadSource" -Destination ".\$arqAgenteZabbix"
} -Credential $Cred
```

Comment: I tried that and it gives me this error:
+ Invoke-Command -Credential $credencial -ScriptBlock {
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Command], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeCommandCommand